# Express isnt loading CSS files

Tags: css, node.js, directory

For some reason my CSS isnt loading, I use sass so it creates a `css` folder outside of the `public` folder, And it just keeps doing that after i try to move it

my folder directory
-node project
-public
+index.html[FOlder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvl3N.png)

-css
+style.css
+index.js (my server)

Here are my links in the css and the middleware im using to serve this in the index

html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

nodejs

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Note im now also getting an error -

"Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

Comment: can you show us your folder structure?

Comment: Ive just added it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve the multiple `static files` you need to add multiple `middlewares` in your `index.js` file

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.static('css'));
```

and link to `CSS` with this line in your `index.html` file

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply, This was the first thing i tried but it didnt work - I assumed that you were only allowed one middleware to serve static files (new to node) and have since solved the issue by playing with my sass compiler settings. But its good to know that i can use this in the future